# Why doesn't python have a simple install command (like mvn install)?

Tags: java, python, maven, groovy, dependencies

I have tried searching for this, but the answer seems to involve over 10 steps. Why can't it have a single command like "mvn install"?

By mvn install, I mean auto download the dependencies and package your project into a final product, which is extremely important.

---

Background: I was trying to write something that can scrape a website and build a GUI out of it and then make some POST request to the website. I'm a java programmer but I wanna do this in python so I can learn and experience the joy of writing with it. I was hoping something for something like [Groovy Grapes](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) for python.

Comment: What do you mean "package your project into the final product"?

Comment: Have you looked at pip? It's the most common python package manager (although people on Linux often just use apt-get or yum)

Comment: There is an article about using distutils for dependency management and packaging for python at http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.2/diveintopython3/html/packaging.html. Then there is http://pybuilder.github.io/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.0.1 of course pip which uses distutils under the hood and works well with virtualenv for managing dependencies in a standalone environment.

Comment: Quicksand: You asked using a Java jargon, which might not be completely obvious to outsiders. So, you want an automated build, which gives a executable which is ready to distribute to clients (self contained etc.)? I think that package managers are not the answer, since they take care of input dependencies only - not bundling them

Answer (score 2):

Ok, based on the comments, it seems that pybuilder is what I'm looking for.
http://pybuilder.github.io/documentation/tutorial.html#.VelDz_mqpBc

If you look at the examples screenshots, it looks almost like maven entirely. The comand **pyb** seems to be the best equivalent of **mvn install**, which is great bec it's only 3 keystrokes.

And note to python neophytes like me: pip is used for grabbing the pybuilder which I believe is the same as downloading/setting up maven itself. And also note that pip is [built into python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) - *batteries included*.